# Issues getting JSON string for chart.js data

Tags: javascript, json, chart.js

I'm getting the following error when trying to get a JSON data string for charts.js

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'datasets' on string '{"datasets":[{"label":"My First dataset","data":[{"x":"2017-01-01","y":35},{"x":"2017-01-15","y":28},{"x":"2017-01-31","y":42}]}]}'
```

The JSON string I'm creating looks exactly the same like the one in an example. Also if I just copy and paste this string and set it as my data it's just working fine.

This is working:

```
            data: {"datasets":[{"label":"My First dataset","data":[{"x":"2017-01-01","y":35},{"x":"2017-01-15","y":28},{"x":"2017-01-31","y":42}]}]},
```

This is not working:

```
.done(function( data ) {
    console.log(data);
        type: 'line',
        data: data });
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't really understand but you probably need to convert the string to javascript object using : JSON.parse(data)

Comment: You didn't understand the problem but you had the correct solution. Thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Data received is in string format. You should call `JSON.parse(data)` on received data in order to access `dataset` property.

Comment: Yea that was my mistake. Stupid me. Thanks ;-)